# How to add surrogate auto-increasing key to table?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I add surrogate key (auto increased key like 1,2,3,4...) to table by spark-sql?

I already did like this.

```
SELECT IDENTITY(1,1) AS table_id, table_1.*
FROM table_1
```

But it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark has a method called [`monotonically_increasing_id`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@monotonically_increasing_id():org.apache.spark.sql.Column). This is more straightforward than `row_number` and more proper to your purpose. You can use it like this:

```
SELECT MONOTONICALLY_INCREASING_ID() AS table_id, t1.*
FROM table_1 t1
ORDER BY <columns>
```

And also, don't forget to add `ORDER BY` to make your surrogate key reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have shown is for SQL Server.  In Spark SQL, you can use `row_number()` to add a column to the result set.  Something like:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col) as table_id, t1.*
FROM table_1 t1;
```